# Is there a better way to assign a Ruby hash while avoiding RuboCop's ABC Size warnings?

Tags: ruby, metrics, static-analysis, rubocop

I have a method that builds a laptop's attributes, but only if the attributes are present within a row that is given to the method:

```
def build_laptop_attributes desk_id, row, laptop
  attributes = {}
  attributes[:desk_number] = room_id if laptop && desk_id
  attributes[:status] = row[:state].downcase if row[:state]
  attributes[:ip_address] = row[:ip_address] if row[:ip_address]
  attributes[:model] = row[:model] if row[:model]
  attributes
end
```

Currently, RuboCop is saying that the [Metric/AbcSize](https://docs.rubocop.org/rubocop/cops_metrics.html#metricsabcsize) is too high, and I was wondering if there is an obvious and clean way to assign these attributes?

Comment: Assuming that the code is technically correct (there is no definition for `room_id`, so i guess it is the name of a parameterless method), I find it well written and easy to understand, as we can see for each attributes, under which conditions it is being set.

Comment: A lot of the code in this method is really just guarding against nil values. There are often better ways to handle this, but it's hard to offer concrete advice without a lot more context.

Comment: @user1934428 thank you, the code base aims to be readable and working. I was just worried that there may have been a way of writing this that would still satisify those two and possibly make it a bit better to read too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Style Guides Provide "Best Practices"; Evaluate and Tune When Needed

First of all, RuboCop is *advisory*. Just because RuboCop complains about something doesn't mean it's wrong in some absolute sense; it just means you ought to expend a little more skull sweat (as you're doing) to see if what you're doing makes sense.

Secondly, you haven't provided a self-contained, executable example. That makes it impossible for SO readers to reliably refactor it, since it can't currently be tested without sample inputs and expected outputs not provided in your original post. You'll need those things yourself to evaluate and refactor your own code, too.

Finally, the [ABC Metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABC_Software_Metric) looks at assignments, branches, and conditionals. You have five assignments, four conditionals, and what looks liks a method call. Is that a lot? If you haven't tuned Rubocop, the answer is "RuboCop thinks so." Whether or not you agree is up to you and your team.

If you want to try feeding Rubocop, you can do a couple of things that might help reduce the metric:

1. Refactor the volume and complexity of your assignments. Some possible examples include:

   - Replace your postfix if-statements with safe navigators (`&.`) to guard against calling methods on `nil`.
   - Extract some of your branching logic and conditionals to methods that "do the right thing", potentially reducing your current method to a single assignment with four method calls. For example:

     ```
     attributes = { desk_number: location, status: laptop_status, ... }
     ```
   - Replace all your multiple assignments with a deconstructing assignment (although Rubocop often complains about those, too).
2. Revisit whether you have the right data structure in the first place. Maybe you really just want an OpenStruct, or some other data object.

Your current code seems readable, so is the juice really worth the squeeze? If you decide that RuboCop is misguided in this particular case, and your code works and passes muster in your internal code reviews, then you can tune the metric's sensitivity in your project's [.rubocop.yml](https://docs.rubocop.org/rubocop/0.89/configuration.html#config-file-locations) or [disable that particular metric](https://docs.rubocop.org/rubocop/0.89/configuration.html#disabling-cops-within-source-code) for just that section of your source code.

Comment: I agree about applying your own judgment. Note that `RuboCop` (since ~0.87) will now count multiple assignments and `&.` correctly and these are typically not helpful to reduce ABCSize anymore.

Answer (score 1):

After reading @Todd A. Jacobs answer, you may want (or not) to write something like this:

```
def build_laptop_attributes desk_id, row, laptop
  desk_number = room_id if laptop && desk_id

  {
    desk_number: desk_number,
    status: row[:state]&.downcase,
    ip_address: = row[:ip_address],
    model: row[:model]
  }.compact
end
```

This reduces has the advantage of reducing the number of calls to `[]=`, as well as factorizing many `if`s in a single `compact`.

In my opinion, it is more readable because it is more concise and because the emphasis is completely on the correspondence between your keys and values.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative version to reduce the amount of conditionals (assuming you are checking for nil / initialized values):

```
def build_laptop_attributes desk_id, row, laptop
  attributes = {}
  attributes[:desk_number] = room_id if laptop && desk_id
  attributes[:status] = row[:state]&.downcase
  attributes[:ip_address] = row[:ip_address]
  attributes[:model] = row[:model]

  attributes.compact
end
```

There is an additional `.compact` as a cost of removing assignments checks.